# concatenate string and emoji in python

Tags: python, tkinter, chatbot, emoji

I have prepared a chatbot using tkinter python. I want to display the emoji after every message. How to concatenate string and emoji in chatbot? The problem doesn't arise if I use a normal string. For example, I have tried this -

```
import codecs
x = 'Hello \\U0001F600 world'
codecs.decode(x, 'unicode_escape')
```

Output

```
'Hello  world'
```

But when I implement the same in a chatbot it's giving - 
code -

```
face = '\\U0001F600'
face_decode = codecs.decode(face, 'unicode-escape')
def send():
           msg = EntryBox.get("1.0",'end-1c').strip()
           EntryBox.delete("0.0",END)
           if msg != '':
                   ChatLog.config(state = NORMAL)
                   ChatLog.insert(END, "You: " + msg + '\n\n', )
                   ChatLog.config(font =  ("Arial", 14, 'bold'))

                   res = chatbot_response(msg)
                   ChatLog.insert(END, "Tanya: " + res + face + '\n\n')
```

Here msg and res are the strings. I am getting the following output

[image: output in the bot]

How to overcome this?

Comment: Hello, you have defined the variable `face_decode` but didn't use it, sure that is what you wanted?

Comment: Also, you can avoid the decoding if you use the `unicodedata` module, you can replace your escape code with `unicodedata.lookup("GRINNING FACE")`. Also makes it easier to understand which unicode character that is at a later time.

Comment: Okay. I wrote face_decode in place of face. I am getting                                            
                                                                                                                   You:hi                                                                                                                                            Tanya:hi there, this is Tanya. How can I help you?ð\x9f\x98\x80

Comment: how to decode the last encoded figures?

Comment: I tried to rebuilt your thing, changing `face` to `face_decode` worked for me, did you change anything else?

Comment: I have made the following changes as you said------------------------------------                                              
face = unicodedata.lookup("GRINNING FACE") ---------  
face_decode = codecs.decode(face, 'unicode-escape')----------
res = chatbot_response(msg)-----------                                          ChatLog.insert(END, "Tanya: " + res + face_decode + '\n\n')---------------   
(hyphens are just to differentiate the lines)

Comment: If you use the unicodedata lookup, the result will already be decoded, you only need the decoding if you write it like this `'\\U0001F600'`. With the lookup, you can skip this step.

Comment: I acknowledge your time sir, but It's not working either. It's working outside, but it's not inside the bot..

Comment: `root = tk.Tk()|
eb = tk.Text(root)|
cl = tk.Text(root)|
eb.pack()|
cl.pack()|
face = unicodedata.lookup("GRINNING FACE")|
def send():|
    msg = eb.get("1.0",'end-1c').strip()|
    eb.delete("0.0", tk.END)|
    if msg != '':|
        cl.config(state = tk.NORMAL)|
        cl.insert(tk.END, "You: " + msg + '\n\n', )|
        cl.config(font =  ("Arial", 14, 'bold'))|
        res = "placeholder"|
        cl.insert(tk.END, "Tanya: " + res + face + '\n\n')|
button = tk.Button(root, command=send, text="Send")|
button.pack()|
root.mainloop()|
`

Comment: replace | with newline and match the indentation to yours, also `import tkinter as tk` and `import unicodedata`. I use python 3.8, that works on my machine